# Upload files (in chunk) using GraphQL conventions and .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, graphql

Iam using Graphql.Net with conventions.

https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/conventions

How do I implement (or say access file (chunk)) file upload (I am using [vue-simple-uploader](https://github.com/simple-uploader/vue-uploader))

vue simple uploader sends data in chunk.

so apart from getting data to end point, it also requires files to be merged in the end. is this possible with graphql.net with conventions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, files are out of GraphQL specification and should be implemented next to GraphQL handler. We came up with the following solution:

Create middleware to serve files by URL (you can use filepath, filename, ID etc.) and return those URLs from GraphQL queries
As for upload, we add files into HTTP headers (like in multipart/form-data) and only passing their names (paths/IDs) as mutation's fields arguments. Later we can (pre)process those streams from HttpContext in controller (for example) to put Streams into UserContext where they can be accessed by their names (paths/IDs) from the mutation methods.

[Source](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/conventions/issues/156)